# Using jQuery replacing content (tags and texts) between two div tags with named id's

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

Let's say I have the following HTML:

```html
<div id="before">Contents of before div</div>
<div>Between #1</div>
<p>Between #2</p>
<div>Between #3</div>
<div id="after">Contents of after div</div>
```

How do I remove everything between the div's with id=before and id=after, so the result is as follows:

```html
<div id="before">Contents of before div</div>
<div id="after">Contents of after div</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to restructure the HTML at all?

Comment: @maxshuty No, I wasn't able to add a div to contain the between tags, thus my problem.  If I could then I would simply replace that div with the HTML.  Therefore Mamun's answer is perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [**`.nextUntil()`**](https://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/):

> Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.

```js
$('#before').nextUntil('#after').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="before">Contents of before div</div>
<div>Between #1</div>
<p>Between #2</p>
<div>Between #3</div>
<div id="after">Contents of after div</div>
```

**Update:** Insert *htmlString* after remove:

```js
$('#before').nextUntil('#after').remove();
var htmlString = '<div>This element is inserted after the element #before </div>';
$(htmlString).insertAfter("#before");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="before">Contents of before div</div>
<div>Between #1</div>
<p>Between #2</p>
<div>Between #3</div>
<div id="after">Contents of after div</div>
```

Comment: After remove(), to add the HTML after #before, I used $(htmlstring).insertAfter("#before").  If you could update your answer to include the insert step, that would be great.

Comment: @PaulS.Lee, I don't see any issue here, please check the second answer:)

Comment: Thanks for the update, making the answer complete to the question.  That's precisely what I did.   No issue.  I wish I can vote your answer twice :-).